# Парсинг outlook python

Tags: python

У меня есть парсер, проблема в том что я не могу спарсить все данные. Данный код парсит последнее сообщение. Если у вас пример или подскажите.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(5) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
print(body_content)
```

Comment: почитайте документацию про inbox.Items.Ваш код делает ровно то, что вы ему сказали. Сказали прочитать только последнее сообщение (message = messages.GetLast()) - получите только последнее сообщение.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш совет, уже разобрался.